# Remove alphanumeric content from a list in python using regex

Tags: python

I have a list as below:

```
list1 = ['Persuasion', 'by', 'u159', 'Austen', '1818', 'Chapter', '1', 'Sir', 'u888', 'Elliot', 'of', 'u650', 'Hall', 'u123', 'in', 'u245', 'u963', 'was', 'a', 'man', 'who', 'u400']
```

I tried printing my list with following `for` comprehension to print all strings which starts with `u` followed by any digit but getting empty list as output.This is what I have tired:

`[print(x) for x in list1 if x == re.search('^u[1-9]+', x)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
[x for x in list1 if re.search('^u[1-9]+', x)]
```

Don't use `print(x)` inside list comprehension that will make a syntax error.

Comment: without $ sign in RE it will also search "u123asd"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare x with search result which is returning a match object on success.
Do this instead,

```
[x for x  in list1 if re.search('^u[1-9]+', x)]
```

Comment: Why you changing again, Make it proper @MYGz Done it proper way,

Answer (score 0):

re.search return a RE object if it search a string otherwise return None
Use this code

```
[x for x in list1 if re.search('^u[1-9]+$', x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather you can use filter method

```
filter(lambda x: re.search('^u[1-9]+', x) != None, list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When `re.search('^u[1-9]+', x)` succeeds, it does not return the string `x`, but instead a `MatchObject` instance. (See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more info.)

Also, if you want a list of all strings matching the regex pattern, you should not use `print(x)` within the list comprehension, which would cause the list to be populated with `None` objects.

So what you're looking for is:

```py
[x for x in list1 if re.search('^u[1-9]+', x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[x for x in list1 if re.search('^u[1-9]+', x)]
```

You did a mistake here that you are comparing x to re.search, but re.search will return a re.search object if it match otherwise None